# Not exactly a question: whoopsie problems during dist-upgrade in saucy

Tags: apt, upgrade, bug-reporting

It's not a question but I think it can be useful ...

While dist-upgrading a saucy custom DVD, I've got an error about whoopsie:

```
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/whoopsie not found.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/whoopsie_0.2.24.1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/whoopsie not found.
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/whoopsie_0.2.24.1ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Investigating a little, I've found that on my other pc, running precise, /etc/init.d/whoopsie, was a symlink:

```
whoopsie -> /lib/init/upstart-job*
```

while in chrooted saucy looking for /etc/init.d/whoopsie I've got *cannot access /etc/init.d/whoopsie: No such file or directory*

So I've created the above symlink and finally dist-upgrade worked fine.

Silvia

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 (i.e. Saucy) and have Whoopsie installed but don't have /etc/init.d/whoopsie OR /lib/init/upstart-job.

I'm also trying to create a custom Ubuntu 13.10 LiveCD and can confirm the above fix works when I run it in the chroot.